# Блокировка приложения через файл hosts

Tags: php, веб-программирование, сервер, hosts, gameserver

Необходимо сделать так, чтоб приложение танки (https://worldoftanks.ru/) не работало, и переустановка не помогла. При этом вся история должна быть убедительной и выглядеть, как будто оно само всё "сломалось".
Решено использовать файл hosts.
Вопрос: как узнать, с каким сервером соединяется приложение во время работы, чтоб добавить этот адрес в hosts?

Answer (score 2):

Эх, за что же вы так) Список всех хостов:

RU1 —  Россия, Москва
(login.p1.worldoftanks.net)

RU2 —  Россия, Москва
(login.p2.worldoftanks.net)

RU3 —  Германия, Франкфурт
(login.p3.worldoftanks.net)

RU4 —  Россия, Екатеринбург
(login.p4.worldoftanks.net)

RU5 —  Россия, Москва
(login.p5.worldoftanks.net)

RU6 —  Россия, Москва
(login.p6.worldoftanks.net)

RU7 —  Россия, Москва
(login.p7.worldoftanks.net)

RU8 —  Россия, Красноярск
(login.p8.worldoftanks.net)

RU9 —  Россия, Хабаровск
(login.p9.worldoftanks.net)

RU10 —  Казахстан, Павлодар
(login.p10.worldoftanks.net)

SEA1 —  Республика Сингапур, Сингапур
(login.worldoftanks-sea.com)

CH1 —  Китай, Лангфанг, провинция Хэбэй (China Unicom, север)
(login.cn-n.worldoftanks.cn)

CH2 —  Китай, Шанхай (China Telecom, центр/восток)
(login.p1.cn-s.worldoftanks.cn)

CH3 —  Китай, Чэнду, провинция Сычуань (China Telecom, юго-запад/северо-запад)
(login.p2.cn-s.worldoftanks.cn)

CH4 —  Китай, Гуанчжоу, провинция Гуандун (China Telecom, юг)
(login.p3.cn-s.worldoftanks.cn)

EU1 —  Германия, Мюнхен
(login.p1.worldoftanks.eu)

EU2 —  Нидерланды, Амстердам
(login.p2.worldoftanks.eu)

US1 —  США, Вашингтон
(login-p1.worldoftanks.com)

US2 —  США, Лос-Анджелес
(login-p2.worldoftanks.com)

ROK1 —  Республика Корея, Сеул
(login.worldoftanks.kr)